# Setting up .htaccess for the first time

Tags: .htaccess

Totally lost on how to set up a .htaccess file, bunch of stuff and only been able to redirect and set index.

I have a site `https://subdomain.domain.com/views/list.html` and 
I want it to show up as `https://subdomain.domain.com`
Ive been able to hide the `views/list.html` from that main page with `DirectoryIndex views/list.html` but when i come back to it from within the website it still shows up as subfolder.
Also is it possible for other subfolder files to not show up as subfolder but as something else? e.g. `https://subdomain.domain.com/views/add.html` show up as  `https://subdomain.domain.com/addproduct`

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about trying PHP indexing? Make a folder structure and place the indexer in the correct folder. As for the subbing, it should be possible, least from what I recall.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP indexing. Wouldn't know where to start.